# I need help to understand cv::mixChannels

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

i have made some corrections to documentation of [cv::mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) as seen [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/5704/files). but i think there are some corrections needed to parameter descriptions.

for example description of `fromTo` for `const int* fromTo` and `const std::vector<int>& fromTo` is the same.

```
CV_EXPORTS void mixChannels(const Mat* src, size_t nsrcs, Mat* dst, size_t ndsts,
                        const int* fromTo, size_t npairs);
CV_EXPORTS void mixChannels(InputArrayOfArrays src, InputOutputArrayOfArrays dst,
                        const int* fromTo, size_t npairs);
CV_EXPORTS_W void mixChannels(InputArrayOfArrays src, InputOutputArrayOfArrays dst,
                               const std::vector<int>& fromTo);

Parameters
    src ...
    dst ....
    fromTo  array of index pairs specifying which channels are copied and where; fromTo[k*2]
    is a 0-based index of the input channel in src, fromTo[k*2+1] is an index of the output
    channel in dst; the continuous channel numbering is used: the first input image channels
    are indexed from 0 to src[0].channels()-1, the second input image channels are indexed
    from src[0].channels() to src[0].channels() + src[1].channels()-1, and so on, the same
    scheme is used for the output image channels; as a special case, when fromTo[k*2] is
    negative, the corresponding output channel is filled with zero .
```

i need some help on this matter.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll have a look at this later.. but are you sure that this kind of question is on-topic here?

Comment: hi Miki, thank you for your response. i don't know here is the right platform but i just asked.

Comment: I believe the description of `fromTo` is correct. It might be clarified somehow, but apart from a diagram it will be hard to explain in words. Do you have an issue with a specific part of the description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you change "array **or** vector of matrices" to simply "array of matrices"?

Regarding the `fromTo` argument, I'll try to deconstruct the paragraph.

```
array of index pairs specifying which channels are copied and where;
```

It will be in the form [In, Out, In, Out, In, Out, ...]. Each value in the array will be an integer representing a channel in one of the images. The mapping between these integers and the actual channels is explained later.

```
fromTo[k*2] is a 0-based index of the input channel in src,
fromTo[k*2+1] is an index of the output channel in dst;
```

This just repeats that the values of the `fromTo` array are alternating between input and output, and will be numbers referencing channels.

```
the continuous channel numbering is used: the first input image channels
are indexed from 0 to src[0].channels()-1, the second input image
channels are indexed from 
src[0].channels() to src[0].channels() + src[1].channels()-1, and so on,
```

This explains the numbering scheme. The concept is very simple and maybe obscured by the formalism. `src[0]` is the first input image, `src[1]` is the second input image.

If we have two input images with three channels each, we are just going to name the channels like this: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. As you can see, the first image's channels are numbered 0, 1, 2 ("`0 to src[0].channels()-1`") and the second image's channels are numbered 3, 4, 5 ("`src[0].channels()`" (i.e: 3) "`to src[0].channels() + src[1].channels()-1`" (i.e: 3 + 3 - 1 = 5))

It's a fancy way of saying that we just take each input in turn and continue increasing the channel number even when moving to the next image.

```
the same scheme is used for the output image channels;
```

The input series and the output series have a numbering sequence independent from one another.

```
as a special case, when fromTo[k*2] is negative, 
the corresponding output channel is filled with zero .
```

Among the pairs of Input/Output channels, if there is something like `-1, 3`, the output channel represented by the index 3 will be filled with zeros.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. I edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems quite clear to me. In my opinion it can eventually be improved in two ways:

1. more *chatty*
2. more *mathematical*

Also I'll leave *input array or vector of matrices*.

Probably it will be useful is `fromTo` was a `const std::vector<Vec2i>` (index pairs), but that will break too much code, I suppose.

---

**Chatty**

Something like:

**fromTo**: array of indices specifying which channels are copied and where. Even indices represent the *from* channel in *src*, while odd indices represent the *to* channel in *dst*. When an even index is negative, the corresponding *to* channel is filled with zeros. In case of multiple images, the indices of the second image follow the indices of the first image, and so on.

**Mathematical**

Something like:

**fromTo**: array in the form `\[ from^{0}_{0}, to^{0}_{0}, ... from^{0}_{src[0].channels()-1}, to^{0}_{src[0].channels()-1}, ..., from^{i}_{j}, to^{i}_{j}, ... \]`, where:

- *from* is the source image
- *to* is the destination image
- *i* is the index of the source and destination image into *src* and *dst*,
- *j* is the channel, from 0 to *src[i].channels()-1*

When a *from* index is negative, the following *to* channel is filled with zeros.

---

Just some random thoughts... :D